# Do I need "ranlib" / "ar -s" for static linking?

Tags: linker, gnu, binutils, unix-ar

I did not find any proper information if and why I need `ranlib` / `ar -s` for static linking.

Assume I have an application that consists of multiple modules. Each module has its code files in its own folder, and the object files are created in their own folder: `module1/%.c → bin/module1/%.o`. For each module I create an `.a` file: `ar -rc bin/module1.a bin/module1/….o`. The whole program gets compiled with `gcc bin/module1.a … moduleN.a -o bin/app`.

In this scenario **what does creating an index for the `.a` file do**? The compilation and program **works just fine** even if I don't add indexes to the `.a` files. But every example that I found called `ranlib` after the last object file was added to the archive.

The question is not Linux / Mac / Windows specific.

Comment: Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47924864/10095231

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From 'Building And Using Static And Shared "C" Libraries':
(http://docencia.ac.upc.edu/FIB/USO/Bibliografia/unix-c-libraries.html)

"After an archive is created, or modified, there is a need to index it. This index is later used by the compiler to speed up symbol-lookup inside the library, and to make sure that the order of the symbols in the library won't matter during compilation (this will be better understood when we take a deeper look at the link process at the end of this tutorial)."

Answer (score 10):

If you're on a POSIX-compatible system, *no*. According to the [specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/ar.html):

> Whenever the ar utility is used to create or update the contents of such an archive, the symbol table is rebuilt.

The only use for `ar -s` or `ranlib` is to rebuild the symbol table after it has been stripped with the `strip` command.